# Chord of a Parabola (ACTM 2006)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was doing a an ACTM Algebra II math test from 2006 to prepare for the ACTM this year, and I stumbled into this problem:

The height of a ball at time *t* (in secs) is *h(t) = 4t - t<sup>2</sup>* (in meters). After 3 seconds how far has the ball traveled?

a) 3 m 
b) 5 m
c) 8 m
d) 9 m

I was a bit confused when I read the problem, as it modeled *height* as a function of time and not *distance traveled*. Then I thought maybe it was asking for the length of a chord on the parabola given. Can anyone help me with this problem? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The starting height is at $t= 0$ and this is just 0. The ball continually travels up until it reaches its highest point, the vertex of the parabola. You can easily see by graphing, or noticing the zeroes are $0, 4$, that the vertex is at $t= 2$. The height here is $4$. Now, the ball comes down for another second and at $t=3$, the height is $3$. So, the ball traveled $1$ meter down after going up $4$ meters. The total is then $4 + 1 = 5$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ball is going straight up and down:

The distance that the ball travels is equal to the distance it travels upwards plus the distance it travels downwards. If the ball never reaches the maximum height, then the height of the ball at that time is the distance traveled. If it has passed the maximum height, then you must find how far it has fallen from the max height and add that amount to the max height.

To get the max height of a parabola, take a look at it's vertex $(h,k)$, remarking that this is a negative, or downward facing, parabola.